# Can't run app with NotificationContentExtension in lower target version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-extensions

The app's target is iOS 9+. I add Notification Content Extension (IOS 10+) but the app doesn't work. This message appears when I try to run it.

> **App installation failed**
>
> This app contains an app extension that specifies an extension point
> identifier that is not supported on this version of iOS for the value
> of the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in its Info.plist.

I want , if the device IOS 10+, run the app but if the device lower than IOS 10 not run Notification Content Extension. How can I do it?

I don't want to make the projects target IOS10+,because there is a lot of user with old model device that can't support IOS 10+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
if(@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    // your code here.     
}
```